# Java: How to select multiple NON-CONSECUTIVE lines of text in a Text Area, the same way Ctrl functions in MS Word?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextarea

I want to select multiple, non-consecutive lines within a `TextArea`, as shown in this image (but non-consecutive)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtTv.png]

and pass the selected lines (as a `String[]` argument) to a method that is invoked when a `Button` is pressed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Swing a JTextArea only supports contiguous selection.

You could use a `JList` and display each line of text as a separate item in the `JList`. A `JList` does support non contiguous selection and have methods to return the Array of selected lines.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use JLists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information.

Note a JTextArea does support the concept of adding "highlights" to text. You can highlight any piece of text but there is no automatic processing to add/remove highlights so you would need to create a whole new UI to dynamically add and remove highlights which is above my pay grade.

Edit:

As I mentioned you might be able so use a `Highlighter` to track individual selections.

A simple example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextAreaHighlighting extends JPanel
{
    private JTextArea textPane = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    private DefaultHighlighter highlighter =  (DefaultHighlighter)textPane.getHighlighter();

    private Highlighter.HighlightPainter cyanPainter;
    private Highlighter.HighlightPainter yellowPainter;

    public TextAreaHighlighting()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight\nnine\nten" );
        add( new JScrollPane( textPane ) );

        //  Highlight some text

        highlighter.setDrawsLayeredHighlights(false);

        cyanPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.CYAN );
        yellowPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.YELLOW );

        try
        {
            highlighter.addHighlight( 0, 3, cyanPainter );
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble) {}

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JButton addHighlight = new JButton("Highlight Selected");
        buttons.add(addHighlight);
        addHighlight.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    int start = textPane.getSelectionStart();
                    int end = textPane.getSelectionEnd();

                    highlighter.addHighlight( start, end, yellowPainter );
                }
                catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
            }
        });

        //  Add Remove Highlight button

        JButton removeHighlight = new JButton("Remove Selected Highlight");
        buttons.add( removeHighlight );
        removeHighlight.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int start = textPane.getSelectionStart();
                int end = textPane.getSelectionEnd();

                Highlighter.Highlight[] highlights = textPane.getHighlighter().getHighlights();

                for (int i = 0; i < highlights.length; i++)
                {
                    Highlighter.Highlight h = highlights[i];
                    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter thePainter =
                        (DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter)h.getPainter();

                    if (h.getStartOffset() >= start
                    &&  h.getEndOffset() <= end)
                        highlighter.removeHighlight(h);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Pane Highlighting");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextAreaHighlighting());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

But JList won't do the trick for me as well: as far as I've figured out, it only allows to select WHOLE line, while I need to be able to select some part of the line: part from one line, part from another one ("appending" it to existing selection(s), the same way Ctrl functions in MS Word)...

Would be very thankful if you give me a hint or two on possible solutions!!!


Or, if I misled myselft on JList, please, tell me! :)

Comment: Well, one straightforward approach would be to just use, for example, one JTextArea and one JList, to select some text in Text Area, then press a button that puts selected text into JList, and when the latter is filled with necessary strings, just press a button to process JList content as a String[] array...

But maybe it can be done with one text-containing object...

Comment: @Laffy, added example to show how to use "highlighting".

Comment: Oh, I am very greatful! This works, although on my level I don't understand how and why, but it works, and I just need to get String[] array from highlighted elements to do my logic! :D

Thank you!!!